# How to change the image of the clicked item in the listview

Tags: android, listview

In my app i want to change the imageview in the listview on which the user click.in starting i pass the image in the listview throught the adapter class,but on click on the item i want to change the image in the imageview in listview later,how i can change the image at the particluar position.??

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     ListView listView;
 public static int pos = 0;
    String[] Prayers = new String[] { "REFLETINDO A IMAGEM DE CRISTO",
            "PROVIDÊNCIA PARA TODOS OS CASOS", "A CRUZ REVELA O AMOR DE DEUS",
            "REFLETINDO O AMOR DE CRISTO", "CRISTO CRUCIFICADO POR NÓS",
            "AMOR IMENSURÁVEL", "DÁDIVA DO AMOR DE DEUS",
            "NÃO PARA CONDENAR, MAS PARA SALVAR",
            "O CENTRO DE MINHA ESPERANÇA",


    };

    String[] Dias = new String[] { "Dia1", "Dia2", "Dia3", "Dia4", "Dia5",
            "Dia6", "Dia7", "Dia8", "Dia9", "Dia10", "Dia11", "Dia12",
            "Dia13", "Dia14", "Dia15", "Dia16", "Dia17", "Dia18",


    };
    LinearLayout lay1 ,lay2;
    int i=0;
    int img ;

    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

       img = R.drawable.praying_hands_normal ;


       rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
           RowItem item = new RowItem( Dias[i], Prayers[i],img);
           rowItems.add(item);
       }

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
       BaseClass adapter = new BaseClass(this, rowItems);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            // get the position of the clicked item 
        View t = null;
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    pos = position;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,OpenActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

    }
```

**Adapterclass**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder = null;

                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.txtDias = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dias);
                    holder.txtPrayers = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.prayers);
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

                holder.txtPrayers.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
                holder.txtDias.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.praying_hands_normal);
          if(pos == position && OpenActivity.a + OpenActivity.b +
                  OpenActivity.c == 1 || OpenActivity.a + OpenActivity.b +
                  OpenActivity.c == 2)
          {
              holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.praying_hands_bookmark);

          } 

          else if(pos == position && OpenActivity.a + OpenActivity.b +
                  OpenActivity.c == 3 )
          {
              holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.praying_hands_selected);
          }


        return convertView;

}
```

Comment: does you mean you want immediately change the imageview when finger down?

Comment: @  VinceStyling no i want after clicking  on item,new activity will open,and when i return back to activity.,image visible me shoulb be new image.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in the onItemClick() method has "View view" which afaik is the item you pressed. view.findViewById() focuses on that row.

Try this.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     // Add following to your listener
     ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.item_image );
     image.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.new_item_image ));

     // Or
     Drawable img = ( Drawable ) getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.new_item_image ));
     image.setBackground( img );

   }
});
```

Edit: to keep the item changed when you return from your intent, try this

In MainActivity, add an View, Context & ImageView,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public View row;
  public Context ctx;
  public ImageView newImage;

  // your code
```

In the onItemClickListener add this,

```
  row = view; 
  ctx = getBaseContext();
  newImage = ( ImageView ) getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.new_item_image ));
```

Now add a new method called something like "setImage" (in MainActivity class),

```
public void setImage( View row ) {
  ImageView item_image = ( ImageView ) row.findViewById( R.id.item_image );
  item_image.setBackground( newImage );
}
```

When you leave your new activity, call this first,

```
MainActivity.setImage( MainActivity.row );
```

Tell me if this worked, I have not tried it myself.

Comment: @ Jonas B it changing image on click.,but when i return back to activity from another activity..,the image i change on click got disappear and previous image get visible..,how can i fix the new image permanently on click..??

Comment: @ Jonas B by update my adapter class i getting the image change..,but when i click on another item the image changed for previously clicked item to default..,how to change it permanently..please help me in that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781709/change-image-of-listivews-item-permanently  here is the link

Answer (score 0):

the ListView refresh after you come back to Activity, in this time, each item's getView() would execute but your `RowItem` still hold the old ImageId, that's why the previous image get visible, just modify the `RowItem`'s imageId when item clicking :

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    RowItem rowItem = rowItems.get(position);
    rowItem.setImageId(R.drawable.new_item_image);

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,OpenActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

--------------- Update at 3 hours later ---------------

save the `BaseClass` outside of onCreate() method, notify dataset changed at onResume() :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BaseClass adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        adapter = new BaseClass(this, rowItems);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

by the way, you should post the `BaseClass` code as well.

Comment: @ VinceStyling it giving error at defining parent.getIem on click.,how to solve that??

Comment: can you see the `rowItems` which you define in Activity?

Comment: i set the image in the xml on imageview..then on click i set the new image on imageview through view as Jonas B told..,then also that image is not permanent..why so.??

Comment: actually getItem is in adapter class and you are saying to accessing it in MainActivity. through RowItem activity(bean class)so getItem function is undefine for it.so i am getting error

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, it's get() isn't getItem().

Comment: Sorry but it didn't change the image atall

Comment: does the getView() invoke when you came back?

Comment: i check it right now..,no it is not invoking on returning

Comment: no matter how, you should make getView() invoke after change the ImageId

Comment: @ VinceStyling  i am trying but nothing is happing.

Comment: bt i already post the getview method of the BaseClass  @ VinceStyling

Comment: it only showing me the image on click only,after on returing to the acitivty back previous image is visible

Comment: if i add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); on resume then nothing happen

Comment: I believe your Adapter was extended by `ArrayAdapter`, turn to extend BaseAdapter.